# How not to display the captions when video starts playing using videojs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am using Video.js for a customized video player and by default it shows the captions when video starts playing. How can I have the closed captions disabled on start/autoplay?

```js
var myPlayer = _V_("myPlayer");
var videoPlaying = true;

// video captions button
var myCaption = myPlayer.controlBar.addChild("button");

// Styling to empty button
$(".vjs-control-text").empty();

// Add class to captions
myCaption.addClass("vjs-captions-icon");
myCaption.addClass("vjs-captions-icon-on");

// Adding functionality to captions button
$(".vjs-captions-icon").on('touchstart', function() {
  $('div.vjs-captions.vjs-text-track').toggle();
  $('.vjs-control-bar .vjs-captions-icon').toggleClass('vjs-captions-icon-on').toggleClass('vjs-captions-icon-off');
});
```

```css
.vjs-captions-icon-on {
  background: url(../img/caption_button.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.vjs-captions-icon-off {
  background: url(../img/caption_button_off.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<video id="myPlayer" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin" width="1024px" height="768px" controls autoplay preload data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
  <source src="../video/brandt.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <track class="caption" kind="captions" src="../video/brandt.vtt" type="text/plain" srclang="en" label="English" default/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing answer from [gkatsev](https://github.com/gkatsev) answered here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2124

Quoting from there.

> showing - the text track is visible and updating and firing events
>   disabled - the track track isn't visible and isn't firing events
>   hidden - the track track isn't visible but it is firing events.
>
> So, to hide a track, you can do:
>
> ```
> player.textTracks()[0].mode = 'disabled';
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old - but I was researching this issue, and had worked out a script using the accepted answer, until I realised:

In the `<track>` tag, just delete the **default** tag at the end of it.

e.g. instead of

```
<track class="caption" kind="captions" src="../video/brandt.vtt" type="text/plain" srclang="en" label="English" default/>
```

do

```
<track class="caption" kind="captions" src="../video/brandt.vtt" type="text/plain" srclang="en" label="English"/>
```